# How to Read USB Serial Port and Fetch Files from Android Smart TV in Android App?

Tags: android, kotlin, serial-port, usb, smart-tv

I'm developing an Android app for Android Smart TVs, and I'm facing difficulties accessing data from a connected USB device within the app. The app needs to detect USB devices connected to the Android Smart TV and fetch files from the USB storage.

I've implemented the necessary steps to detect USB devices and request permission to access them using the UsbManager and UsbDeviceConnection classes. However, I'm unable to access the content inside the USB drive using standard Java I/O classes for file operations.

Here's a summary of what I've tried:

1. Detecting USB devices connected to the Android Smart TV using UsbManager.
2. Requesting permission to access USB devices using UsbManager.requestPermission().
3. Attempting to read files from the USB storage using FileInputStream and File classes.

Despite implementing these steps, I'm unable to access the data from the USB device.

Can someone provide guidance or a working example on how to properly access and fetch files from a connected USB device on an Android Smart TV within an Android app? Are there any specific considerations or limitations for accessing USB storage on Android Smart TVs that I should be aware of?

Any insights, code snippets, or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code

```
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.hardware.usb.UsbConstants
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection
import android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint
import android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Environment
import android.util.Log
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.IOException
import java.nio.ByteBuffer

class SerialPortReader {

    private lateinit var usbManager: UsbManager
    private lateinit var usbInterface: UsbInterface
    private lateinit var usbEndpoint: UsbEndpoint
    private lateinit var usbDeviceConnection: UsbDeviceConnection
    private val ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.example.usb_seriel_image.USB_PERMISSION"

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun fetchConnectedUsbDevices(context: Context): List<Map<String, String>> {
        val usbDeviceDetailsList = mutableListOf<Map<String, String>>()

        try {
            usbManager = context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE) as UsbManager

            // Create a PendingIntent for USB permission request

            val permissionIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    context, 0, Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                )

            // Register a BroadcastReceiver to handle USB permission request result
            context.registerReceiver(
                usbPermissionReceiver, IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION),
                Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
            )

            for (device in usbManager.deviceList.values) {
                val usbDeviceDetails = mutableMapOf<String, String>()

                usbDeviceDetails["deviceName"] = device.productName.toString()
                usbDeviceDetails["manufacturer"] = device.manufacturerName.toString()
                usbDeviceDetails["productId"] = device.productId.toString()
                usbDeviceDetails["vendorId"] = device.vendorId.toString()
                usbDeviceDetailsList.add(usbDeviceDetails)

                if (!device.productName!!.contains("Wireless_Device")) {
                    // Request permission to access USB device
                    usbManager.requestPermission(device, permissionIntent)
                    getImageDataFromUsbDevices(context!!, device)
                } else {
//                    return listOf(mapOf("message" to "No USB devices found"))
                }
            }
        } catch (error: Exception) {
            Log.e("[USB_SERIAL]", error.toString())
        }
        return usbDeviceDetailsList
    }

    fun getImageDataFromUsbDevices(context: Context, usbDevice: UsbDevice) {
        usbManager = context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE) as UsbManager

        val permissionIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, 0, Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )
        usbInterface = usbDevice.getInterface(0)
        usbEndpoint = usbInterface.getEndpoint(0)

        usbDeviceConnection = usbManager.openDevice(usbDevice)
        usbDeviceConnection.claimInterface(usbInterface, true)
        usbManager.requestPermission(usbDevice, permissionIntent)
        val imageData = readImagesFromUsbDevice(context, usbDevice)
        val data = getImageData(usbDevice)
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.size)
        saveImage(bitmap)

        usbDeviceConnection.releaseInterface(usbInterface)
        usbDeviceConnection.close()
    }

    private fun getImageData(usbDevice: UsbDevice): ByteArray {
        val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(64 * 1024)
        val packetSize = usbDevice.getInterface(0).getEndpoint(0).maxPacketSize

        while (buffer.position() < buffer.capacity()) {
            usbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(
                usbEndpoint, buffer.array(), buffer.position(),
                Math.min(packetSize, buffer.remaining()), 0
            )
        }

        return buffer.array()
    }

    private fun saveImage(bitmap: Bitmap) {
        val sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        val imagePath = "$sdCard/ImageFromUsb.jpg"
        val fileOutputStream: FileOutputStream
        val file = File(imagePath)

        try {
            fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream)
            fileOutputStream.flush()
            fileOutputStream.close()
            Log.d("[USB_SERIAL]", "Image saved at $imagePath")
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e("[USB_SERIAL]", e.toString())
        }
    }

    private val usbPermissionReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            if (intent?.action == ACTION_USB_PERMISSION) {
                val granted = intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, true)
                val device = intent.getParcelableExtra<UsbDevice>(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY)
                if (granted && device != null) {
                    // Permission granted, proceed with accessing the USB device
                    getImageDataFromUsbDevices(context!!, device)
                } else {
                    // Permission denied, handle accordingly
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Function to read images from USB device
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    fun readImagesFromUsbDevice(context: Context, usbDevice: UsbDevice): List<Bitmap> {
        val imageBitmaps = mutableListOf<Bitmap>()
        val usbDeviceConnection = usbManager.openDevice(usbDevice)

        val permissionIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, 0, Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )
        // Check if USB device connection is null
        if (usbDeviceConnection != null) {
            val usbInterface = usbDevice.getInterface(0)
            val usbEndpoint = usbInterface.getEndpoint(0)

            // Access files on the USB drive
            val usbRootDirectory = Environment.getStorageDirectory()
            val usbDrive = File(usbRootDirectory, "/")

            val usbDeviceRootDirectory = getUsbDeviceRootDirectory(context, usbDevice)
//            val usbDrive = File(usbRootDirectory, "/")

// Get all files from the USB drive
            val allFiles = getAllFilesFromUsbDrive(usbDrive)
            // Filter image files (you can adjust file extensions as needed)
            val imageFiles = usbDrive.listFiles { _, name ->
                name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".jpleg") || name.endsWith(".png")
            }

            // Read and decode each image file
            imageFiles?.forEach { file ->
                try {
                    val inputStream = FileInputStream(file)
                    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
                    inputStream.close()
                    imageBitmaps.add(bitmap)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e("USB_IMAGE_READ", "Error reading image file: ${file.absolutePath}", e)
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("USB_CONNECTION", "Failed to open USB device connection")
        }

        return imageBitmaps
    }

    fun getAllFilesFromUsbDrive(directory: File): List<File> {
        val fileList = mutableListOf<File>()

        // Check if the directory exists and is a directory
        if (directory.exists() && directory.isDirectory) {
            val files = directory.listFiles()

            // Loop through all files in the directory
            files?.forEach { file ->
                if (file.isDirectory) {
                    // Recursively call the function to get files from subdirectories
                    fileList.addAll(getAllFilesFromUsbDrive(file))
                } else {
                    // Add the file to the list
                    fileList.add(file)
                }
            }
        }

        return fileList
    }


    fun getUsbDeviceRootDirectory(context: Context, usbDevice: UsbDevice): File? {
        val usbManager = context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE) as UsbManager

        val permissionIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, 0, Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )
        val deviceList = usbManager.deviceList
//        for (deviceEntry in deviceList.entries) {
//            val device = deviceEntry.value
//            if (device.deviceId == usbDevice.deviceId) {
        val usbDeviceConnection = usbManager.openDevice(usbDevice)
        val usbInterface = usbDevice.getInterface(0)
        usbManager.requestPermission(usbDevice, permissionIntent)
        // Iterate over the endpoints to find the one with file system access
        for (endpointIndex in 0 until usbInterface.endpointCount) {
            val endpoint = usbInterface.getEndpoint(endpointIndex)
            if (endpoint.type == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
                // Check if the endpoint supports file system access
//                        if (endpoint.direction == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN) {
//                            // IN endpoint, skip as it's for data from the device to host
//                            continue
//                        } else if (endpoint.direction == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT) {
//                            // OUT endpoint, skip as it's for data from host to device
//                            continue
//                        }

                // Found the correct endpoint, get the device's file system root directory
                val usbDeviceConnection = usbManager.openDevice(usbDevice)
                if (usbDeviceConnection != null && usbDeviceConnection.claimInterface(
                        usbInterface,
                        true
                    )
                ) {
                    // Get the file system root directory
                    val fsRoot = "/mnt/usb_storage/"
                    return File(fsRoot)
                }
            }
        }
//            }
//        }
        return null
    }

//    // Usage example:
//    val usbDeviceRootDirectory = getUsbDeviceRootDirectory(context, usbDevice)
//    if (usbDeviceRootDirectory != null)
//    {
//        // You have successfully obtained the USB device's file system root directory
//        // Now you can perform operations on files within this directory
//    } else
//    {
//        // Failed to obtain the USB device's file system root directory
//        // Handle the error accordingly
//    }

}
```

Comment: `val usbRootDirectory = Environment.getStorageDirectory()` Why do you think getStorageDirectory() has anything to do with a usb drive? You can call this function too with no drive attached. Please tell full path.

Comment: Also tell what getUsbDeviceRootDirectory returns.

Comment: `.... and Fetch Files from Android Smart TV in Android App?` ? You mean: fetch files from usb drive?

Comment: `getUsbDeviceRootDirectory` can return null. You are not taking this in account.

Comment: @blackapps Sorry for the confusion
this line Environment.getStorageDirectory() was this Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
it only gives a directory of storage but that was not a USB device that's only from internal storage

getUsbDeviceRootDirectory only returns wrong directory, some times it returns null

Comment: You did not tell what they returned. I asked for full path. Please tell.

Comment: @blackapps
I want to fetch files from the connected USB serial port that connected with my android tv

Comment: My god.. we know. From the connected drive you mean.  Connected to usb port. Now tell full paths.

Answer (score 0):

Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user select the drive or folders on it.